# How can I run a local DNS Caching nameserver on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, dns

I'm used to running my own DJB dnscache on all unix-like systems I have, i.e. Linux and Mac OSX.  Now that I got me a Vista, I wonder what can I run on it to the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Windows already has a service (DNS Client) that caches dns requests.

Comment: but does it use the rootservers or the ISP-provided DNS servers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it caches the responses from whatever dns servers the network connection is using. You can find the dns servers for your network connections by opening an administrative command prompt, and typing "ipconfig /all" without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in DNS servers are considered server functionality in the Windows world. On Vista, you'll need to get a third-party DNS server. After that, it's as simple as setting your DNS server entry to 127.0.0.1 in your TCP/IP settings.

A quick Google search found [SimpleDNS](http://www.simpledns.com/), but I've never used it and can't attest to how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

The defacto most popular [BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloadables/11) software runs on Windows, as do many other DNS servers.

There's also experimental versions of Unbound for Windows available from [here](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/~wouter/).   Unix versions of Unbound have been available since last year and are already in production use in many ISPs.

The author of Unbound is looking for beta testers for these experimental versions.  If you try Unbound and find any problems please report them at http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/bugs/

Comment: Have you tried to compile unbound under Windows?  Have you succeeded? (I know there are compiled binaries available, but I need to modify the sources.) I am no Linux guy and I haven't even succeeded with compiling the vanilla sources under windows MingW. I strongly suspect that the binaries are cross-compiled from Linux.